# Softlayer API: Order private vlan

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Our requirement is to have 5 virtual machines in 3 different vlans.  At https://control.softlayer.com/network/vlans I don't see option to create private vlans. 
I am wondering is there way to create multiple private vlans using SL API ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a `REST` request to order a `private Vlan`:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
```

Method: POST
Json Payload:

```
{
  "parameters": [
    {
      "location": "AMSTERDAM",
      "packageId": 0,
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 50745 # Private Network Vlan
        },
        {
          "id": 36696 # 8 Static Public IP Addresses
        }
      ],
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "myNewVlan",
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Vlan",
      "itemCategoryQuestionAnswers": [
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 14,
          "answer": 4 # TOTAL_IPS_IN_30_DAYS
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 15,
          "answer": 4 # TOTAL_IPS_IN_12_MONTHS
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 16,
          "answer": "Description of your need for additional IPs"
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 9,
          "answer": "Contact name"
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 10,
          "answer": "Contact job title"
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 11,
          "answer": "qe.testing.qe@gmail.com"
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 12,
          "answer": "72578789"  # CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER
        },
        {
          "categoryId": 53,
          "categoryCode": "static_sec_ip_addresses",
          "questionId": 13,
          "answer": true  # CONTACT_VALIDATED
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:**

- To execute this request, remove the comments please .e.g. # CONTACT_PHONE_NUMBER, # CONTACT_VALIDATED, # TOTAL_IPS_IN_12_MONTHS, # TOTAL_IPS_IN_30_DAYS.
- When all your configuration is ready change from `verifyOrder` to ‘placeOrder’.
  To get `valid item prices`, execute:

  ```
  https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,locationGroupId,item[id,keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]

  Method: GET
  ```

If you want to create multiple items, you can use `API clients` created by SoftLayer: [SoftLayer Api Clients](https://sldn.softlayer.com/)

**References:**

[SoftLayer_Product_Order](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order)

[SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder)

[SoftLayer_Product_Order::verifyOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder/)

[SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Vlan](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Vlan)

[SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price)

[Softlayer-API-Overview](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Softlayer-API-Overview)

Comment: In this example, location is "AMSTERDAM", which is *very* different from the placeOrder call when, for example, ordering iSCSI disks (which use location ID). Can I use location ID instead of "AMSTERDAM", or can I use "ams01"? If I can't, where do I get valid values for the location parameter in *this particular* API call?